# Raspberry pi capture image using java

Tags: java, camera, raspberry-pi

Im trying to take photo on Raspi using Java and Raspi Camera Module, im using codes at below,But i get some error on raspi.
if i run that code on windows it works correctly.
i tried on terminal that commands
   cd Kamera
  javac -classpath .:classes:/home/pi/Kamera/libs/'*' -d . Kamera.java
  sudo java -classpath .:classes:/home/pi/Kamera/libs/'*'  Kamera

I uploaded a photo about errors [img about error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPQqc.png)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Webcam webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
    webcam.open();
    BufferedImage image = webcam.getImage();
    ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", new File("test.png"));
}
```

Comment: Copy and paste the error message as text into the Question please.  Include the full stacktrace.

Comment: Your program is complaining about a missing library (bridj.so). Make sure it is installed correctly and that your program is able to find it.